# Why make extra id column as primary key when look up will be using differnt column?

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

So, I've been leaning sql and database stuff recently as well as hibernate. I'm working on a hibernate project with some tables:

Player(int id, varchar username, varchar name)  where id is pk and both username and id are unique

PCharacter(int id, varchar charName, intp_id) with id as pk and p_id as fk

Item(int id, varchar name, booleanconsumable)  with id as pk

CharacterItem(int char_id, int item_id, int count)  with char_id and item_id as composite key

Now it doesn't make sense why I should include id for Player when most of my look-ups will be with username, doesn't this defeat the purpose of having id as pk? Same with Item, if I changed the pk to the unique attributes (username and name for Player and Item respectively) wouldn't that allow for faster look-ups queries? I understand the necessity of the primary key is to make look-ups faster and allow for both random access and ranged searches. So if this is the case why do I see so many examples using an int id as pk?

Comment: "...I understand the necessity of the primary key is to make look-ups faster ..." - No, the primary key only ensures row uniqueness.

Comment: @TheImpaler I thought that the primary key was used in the underlying B+ tree of most databases as node/leaf value for faster random access and ranged searches. If it's not the primary key that is used for this purpose, what is used for this purpose? Also, if primary key is only used for row uniqueness, does this mean that any column that is unique on a row level will suffice? Thanks

Comment: In case you need to have a foreign key to other table, it makes sense to have id, so that name is not repeated in both the tables. Also primary key creates clustered index, and a index on name would be too big too. most of the APIs would work with ids so it would make sense to have them.

Comment: "I thought that the primary key was used in the underlying B+ tree of most databases as node/leaf value for faster random access and ranged searches..." -- No, but as an implementation detail, primary keys are usually implemented using indexes. In any case, I would suggest you focus on relational theory to understand the definitions correctly.